# Fortify on Visual Studio 2010 C++ project - error MSB6006: -1073741701

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, fortify

I am trying to run fortify on a VS2010 C++ project. I created a very simple hello world project and tried to run fortify with the following command:

`sourceanalyzer.exe -b sample devenv sample.sln /REBUILD`

I keep getting this error:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets(147,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741701.`

the complete build log is:

```
Microsoft (R) Visual Studio Version 10.0.30319.1.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: sample, Configuration: Debug Win
32 ------
1>Build started 09/07/2012 12:13:33 PM.
1>_PrepareForClean:
1>  Deleting file "Debug\sample.lastbuildstate".
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Creating "Debug\sample.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets(147,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741701.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.09
```

I did not get any additional errors. My OS is Windows7 64 bit. My project is a 32 bit console application. I am using fortify 32 bit with version: "Fortify Source Code Analyzer 5.9.5.0007"

I tried browsing microsoft pages for the error, but it is apparently a generic error code.  I am suspecting an incompatibility, but am not able to narrow it down. Can you tell me where I am going wrong?

---

Update: Some more info:

With VS2010's cl.exe, it runs clearly. The error is thrown by Fortify's cl.exe. I checked the error code, and apparently, cl.exe is unable to start. I cross checked with dependency walker, and it is missing a couple of dlls(gpsvc.dll and IEShims.dll). I have a 64 bit Windows installation, but cl.exe is 32 bit and I do not have 32 bit versions of those DLLs. I am not sure if this is the root cause, because they are delay loaded and might not cause the error mentioned.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's ever getting to the Fortify scan. Can you try and build the solution using CL.exe from a command prompt and see if you get the same error?

Comment: I have checked and updated the question with the results...

Comment: -1073741701 is 0xC000007B in hex, which is `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`.  So Fortify's cl.exe is not a valid executable file that the Windows loader knows how to execute.

Comment: @Adam: More likely the invalid image is one of the DLLs that have to be loaded before the process starts running.

Comment: @Adam, @Ben: When I run the cl.exe file as it is without any arguments, I am gtetting `C:\Program Files (x86)\Fortify Software\Fortify 360 v2.6.5\Core\private-bin\IDE>cl.exe -v

Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: Environment not initialized for Fortify SCA Translation
   at wrappersCommon.RunWrapper.RunCmd(String exe, ReadReg reg, String[] args)
   at cl.cl.Main(String[] args)`

Comment: This is a DLL Hell problem, it is most likely finding a 64-bit DLL.  Check the PATH environment variable first.  Diagnose with SysInternals' ProcMon utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the Fortify version. Downloading Fortify360 Version 3.2 resolved the issue.